# Thread1v:signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, iphone

I am Android Developer now switching to IOS, so I am new to IOS development. 
I got error this place

`Thread1v:signal SIGABRT` . how to solve error

```
 -(void)updatePostCountUserDefaults{

NSMutableDictionary *postCount ;

NSNumber *count;

if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"postCount"] !=nil){

    postCount = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"postCount"];

    count = [postCount objectForKey:@"count"];

    count = [NSNumber numberWithInt:([count integerValue] + 1.0)];

    int n = [count integerValue];

    NSLog(@"hey count is : %i" , n);

    [postCount setObject:count forKey:@"count"];

}else{

    postCount = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    count = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];

    [postCount setObject:count forKey:@"count"]; //error- 

}

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:postCount  forKey:@"postCount"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
int num = [count integerValue];
NSLog(@"count is %i " , num);
if([count integerValue] == 4 || [count integerValue] == 12){
    // show rating screen

}
```

pls any help

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace and error message, as they appear in the console?

Comment: how to take console output. i couldn't ...?

Comment: Copy & Paste the console output.

Comment: No error messsage in console

Comment: Which line of code giving this issue?

Comment: You Declared post count as global variable. Inside if loop you added like this postCount = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"postCount"] you are not allocating postcount here. so the nsmutabledictionary is nill. you trying to access the nill may be giving issue. check on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I think the line you marked "error" will not crash. It it `[postCount setObject:count forKey:@"count"];` that will cause the exception. Because `postCount` in that context is an `NSDictionary`, not a mutable dictionary. Therefore, it cannot respond to `setObject:forKey:`.

**EDIT**: The correct code:

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"postCount"] !=nil){
    postCount = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"postCount"] mutableCopy];
    count = [postCount objectForKey:@"count"];
    count = [NSNumber numberWithInt:([count integerValue] + 1.0)];
    int n = [count integerValue];
    NSLog(@"hey count is : %i" , n);
    [postCount setObject:count forKey:@"count"];
}else{...}
```

Comment: I declared as a dictionary `NSMutableDictionary *postCount ` then how?

Comment: Here `postCount = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"postCount"];` `objectForKey:` will return an `id`, which is a pointer to any object. Since the return type is `id` and you declared `postCount` to be `NSDictionary*`, ObjC assumes that you know what you are doing and regard the return value to be `NSDictionary`. But in fact, the returned value is `NSNumber`. Therefore, the the dictionary methods cannot be called on an `NSNumber` instance.

Comment: please suggest  how do i want to change it? it's existing project, there are some bug . just want to fix it

Comment: I am sorry. What I said above is wrong. I dont know why I said `postCount` is an `NSNumber`. It's actually an `NSDictionary`. You are not able to add/remove items in an `NSDictionary`, but you can in an `NSMutableDictionary`. Therefore, to make your codes run, you just need to change `postCount = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"postCount"];` to  `postCount = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"postCount"] mutableCopy];`